# Cell with multiple outcomes

Tags: cells, if

`=DAYS(E#,F#)` sets "G" to number.

I want another cell to override "G" if there is information in "J", yet leave the days counted if "J" is blank.

Comment: This is a very basic `IF` - where in it is your true problem? What have you tried? Tell us a story.

Comment: I am novice honestly, I am not sure if picture uploaded of my screen. I have tried many =IF(OR combinations but lack the proper argument formula. I believe from what I have read is correct IF OR needs to be used but I am unsure I will attempt again shortly and record what I used. This isn't something I usually do but I am trying to adapt to a new set of tasks in my workplace.

Comment: =IF(J3=ISBLANK),(G3=DAYS(F3,E3) this is the closest I can get in text to show exactly what I am trying to accomplish. So I believe it's something extremely simple I am overlooking or, I am trying to do something that cannot be done, or maybe there is another set of formulas between other cells that can be used to accomplish the same thing I suppose

Comment: If multi post isn't allowed I apologize, formulas in use are as follows

Comment: Multiple COMMENTS is not "multiposting". But info that helps understand the question should be Edit-ed into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `=IF(J3=ISBLANK),(G3=DAYS(F3,E3)`

Place either one of these in G3, if that is where you wish to have the result:

1. `=IF( ISBLANK(J3), DAYS(F3,E3), "")`
2. `=IF( J3="", DAYS(F3,E3), "")`
3. `=IF( J3<>"", "", DAYS(F3.E3))`
4. `=IF( NOT( ISBLANK(J3) ), "", DAYS(F3.E3))`

... all of them should be fairly equal, but depending on the situation you might have reason to choose a specific one of them.

Comment: Thank You for the input, I will try this out and let you know 

Comment: Thank you so much my friend that's worked great the very first line! Seems I have alot to learn on these simple things. 